# Featherlight: how to save and re-access "persisted" lightbox?

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I'm using featherlight in a way which requires different lightboxes to be displayed depending on certain conditions. This means I'm stuck calling it from within the JS rather than using data attributes. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if ( filled.length == checked.length ) {
    $.featherlight('#enter-name', { 'persist' : true });
    $('#enter-name-name').trigger('focus');
    $('#enter-name-checked').html(filled.length);
} else {
    $.featherlight('#check-fields', { 'persist' : true });
}
```

This works beautifully the first time; unfortunately the ID will no longer work to select the lightbox after it's removed from the DOM.

I'm told that when the `persist` option is used, the lightbox content is actually detached from the DOM rather than fully removed. How can I save this detached element as a variable and re-open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current behavior should probably change in the future. In the meantime, you should store the return in a variable.

```
var nameDialog = null;

if (...)
   if (!nameDialog) // First time...
     nameDialog = $.featherlight('#enter-name', { 'persist' : true });
   else // After that...
     nameDialog.open();
else
  ...
```

Comment: Pull request to reinsert DOM after close and avoid this trouble welcome.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Seems like something that should ideally be added to the documentation, assuming the behavior doesn't change anytime soon. In any case, I'm glad it's up here for anyone else who runs into this issue.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune did this behavior change on latest version of featherlight? I'm still getting the same behavior and didn't find any PR to fix this. I believe when using persist the DOM should be added back when featherlight is closed, otherwise it's just lost which doesn't seem to be the usecase for using persist

Comment: No change, no PR (yet).
Doesn't necessarily need to be added back, it could persist in the data btw.

Comment: Hi. First, thanks for that answer. do note that i've had tons of problems with implementing featherlight, and not a single place show this kind of example that actually explains why opening twice using the normal open command can cause hell.